# Return initialised object array from method

Tags: java, arrays

I need to use an array of objects in my `main` class (lets call it `Main`). Now, I have a method in `Car`(a different class) that returns an initialised array of objects that I can use in `Main`.

How do I call the method in `Car` to return the array of objects, then assign my object array in `Main` to the returned array?

Like so...

*Main.java*

```
/* code */
Car cars[] = /* what goes here to get the initialised array from Car's method? */
/* Car cars[] = getCars(); doesn't work since I can't call getCars() as Main doesn't inherit from Car */


/* more code */
```

*Car.java*

```
public Car[] getCars()
{
  Car cars[] = new Car[NUM_OF_CARS];
  /* initialised all car elements */
  return cars;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create an instance of class Car,  and call the getCars() method in class Main.

Comment: That just didn't feel like the right thing to do, turns out it wasn't, `static` is what I've used now.

Answer (score 2):

Try making `getCars()` static, that way you can just call `Car.getCars()` from any context without having to initialize a distinct `Car` object.

For example:

```
public static Car[] getCars() {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: make `getCars()` a **static** method.  e.g., in Car.java

```
public static Car[] getCars() { ... }
```

Option 2: in Main.java, instantiate a new Car, then use it.

```
Car aCar = new Car();
Car[] arrayOfCars = aCar.getCars();
```

In your example, Option 1 feels like the right one, since the returned array appears to be independent of any particular car.  However, if the method were "getSimilarCars()" and returned an array of cars that were similar to a particular instance of a Car, then option 2 would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to this:

- Make `Car` double as a "factory" of `Car` objects, changing `getCars` to `static`, or
- Recognize that `getCars` does not belong in `Car`, and should be moved to another class, say, `CarFactory`, instead.

Making a separate "factory" class is often a better choice:

```
public class CarFactory {
    public CarFactory() {
        // Do factory-specific initialization
    }
    public Car[] getCars() {
        ... // Make an array of Car objects
    }
}
```

Now in `Main` class you do this:

```
class Main {
    private static final CarFactory factory = new CarFactory();
    private final Car cars[] = factory.getCars();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Would using the idea of a factory be 'better' than using the `static` keyword?

Comment: @CSStudent Factory lets the class that produces instances of `Car` objects have its own state, independent of the state of the `Car`. It also lets you have multiple separately configured factories, each one producing different subclasses of `Car`s. A solution with making the method `static` is more expedient, though.